# Parse TCP Packet and return response PHP or Ruby

Tags: ruby, sockets, tcp, tcpserver, packets

I am trying to gather information from a TCP connection made to my web server to assist in our troubleshooting efforts, similar to http://speedguide.net/analyzer.php tool.

We have a simple PHP server script test page that users connect that returns their private IP to an AJAX call waiting for the response.

I would like to either build on that or prefer using Ruby.  I played with the PacketFu lib and get all the information I think I need, however, I'm having trouble with the recipe to combine it all:

1. listen on port x,
2. parse the packet
3. respond back to client.

Using Ruby's TCPServer I can easily handle 1 and 3.  With Packetfu, 2.

I've coded with PHP in the past but only HTML-based, no sockets.  And I'm not really all that familiar with Ruby sockets either.

Though the packet stream and client.accept don't seem to play nice.  The packets aren't always IP or TCP meeting the `Packetfu::Packet.is_ip?` or `is_tcp?`.

Could someone point me in the right direction or give me some practical example of how I might combine the two, or adjust my thinking on how I would accomplish this task?

This is the Playground code:

```
require 'socket'
require 'json'
require 'packetfu'

iface = ARGV[0] || "eno1"
server = TCPServer.open(31337)

cap = PacketFu::Capture.new(:iface => iface, :start => true, :promisc => true)

loop {
  cap.stream.each do |p|
    pkt = PacketFu::Packet.parse(p)
    if pkt.is_ip? || pkt.is_tcp?
      if pkt.tcp_dport == 31337
        print "Source Addr: #{pkt.ip_saddr}\n"
        print "Source Port: #{pkt.tcp_src}\n"
        print "Destination Addr: #{pkt.ip_daddr}\n"
        print "Destination Port: #{pkt.tcp_dport}\n"
        print "TCP Options: #{pkt.tcp_options.inspect}\n"
        print "TCP Win: #{pkt.tcp_win}\n"
        print "TCP SYN?: #{pkt.tcp_flags.syn}\n"
        print "TCP ACK?: #{pkt.tcp_flags.ack}\n"
        print "TCP FLAGS ALL: #{pkt.tcp_flags.inspect}\n"
        print "TTL: #{pkt.ip_ttl}\n"
        print "IP FRAG: #{pkt.ip_frag}\n"
       end
    end

    client = server.accept       # Wait for a client to connect
    h = { ipaddress: client.peeraddr[2] }
    client.puts h.to_json
    client.close
  end
}
```

This is the output:

```
Source Addr: 172.20.0.15
Source Port: 41165
Destination Addr: 172.20.0.10
Destination Port: 31337
TCP Options: "NOP,NOP,TS:216432150;57946250"
TCP Win: 229
TCP SYN?: 0
TCP ACK?: 1
TCP FLAGS ALL: #<struct PacketFu::TcpFlags urg=0, ack=1, psh=0, rst=0, syn=0, fin=0>
TTL: 61
IP FRAG: 16384
```

This is the browser response:

```
{"ipaddress":"172.20.0.15"}
```

Comment: It's difficult to read your question. Please take the time to format it using correct grammar. That helps us help you. I'd also recommend reading "[ask]", especially the linked pages.

Comment: Using `print "...\n"` is a really odd thing to do when `puts "..."` adds a newline for you.

Comment: You mean `is_ip? && is_tcp?` presumably. It can't be TCP without being IP in the first place.

Comment: @tadmain.  Thank you for your response.  Syntax was taken directly from the packetfu-syn.rb example.  Same with the if statement for is_ip? and is_tcp?  I did not take the time to change it as it was trivial at this stage in getting a working example.

Comment: @tinman.  Thank you.  I will endeavor to improve.